# SQL Server stored procedure with Ado

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm not sure if a stored procedure is the correct path here so first, I'll explain what I need to accomplish.

I need to query one table with a variable as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.partList 
WHERE column1 = 'order_no';
```

Then, I need to query another table as such:

```
SELECT [serial_no] 
FROM db.resultsList;
```

Finally I need to iterate through the results of the above, and return the first [serial_no] from db.partList that is not in the list produced.

The original programmer was doing this in a way that was blowing up the customer's network unnecessarily.  There shouldn't be any reason this can't be done locally.  Now I'm here to clean it up.

Thanks in advance.

So my questions are, would this be correct use of a stored procedure? If so, could someone perhaps give me some sample code to start working with? I don't often have to dive that deep into SQL Server.

This is SQL Server 2012.

I've got some example code of how I would do it in other languages if needed.  I'm just not familiar enough with stored procedures to do this quickly.

Comment: please add table structure, data sample, and expected results

Comment: You can do this in a single query with joins. The issue is what you mean by the "first" serial_no in db.partList. First by what measure?

Comment: Did this quickly in VBA, should be close.
`Public Sub nextPick(line_no as String)
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [serial_no] FROM [db.resultsList]"
set rst2 = cmd.Execute()
do while not rst.EOF = True
 w = 1
 x = 1
 Do While serialFound = False
  command.CommandText = "SELECT [serial_no] FROM [db.partList] WHERE [serial_no] = '" & rst2(x) & "'"
  Set rst = rst.Execute()
  SELECT CASE rst.EOF 
   CASE False
    x = x + 1
    serialFound = False
    rst.close
   CASE True
    nextPick = rst(w)
    Exit Do
 Loop
 rst.close
 w = w + 1
 Loop
rst2.close
conn.close
end sub`

Comment: The above will find the first record in the db.partsList table that is not in the db.resultsList table, and return it as a string.

Comment: I boogered the top, it should be `Function nextPick(line_no as String) as String`.

Comment: Sure, but you're making it overly complicated when it can be done in a single query without iterating over two result sets in an awkward while loop.

Comment: Would you be bothered to explain to me how?

Comment: Your function is doing what a relational database does quickly by itself with a join. For example, `Public Function nextPick(line_no as String) As String cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 rL.[serial_no] FROM [db.resultsList] AS rL JOIN [db.partList] AS pL ON pL.[serial_no] = rL.[serial_no];" Set rst2 = cmd.Execute() nextPick = rst2!serial_no End Function` or something like that. If you need to add a parameter based on, say, order_no, you can add that in to the query as well, but I'd recommend you use a stored procedure for that instead of a manually written query (to prevent SQL injection).

Comment: Actually I just realised you're looking for parts NOT in the other one, so the query would be `SELECT TOP 1 pL.[serial_no] FROM [db.partList] AS pL LEFT JOIN [db.resultList] AS rL ON rL.[serial_no] = pL.[serial_no] WHERE rL.[serial_no] IS NULL;` But the same principle applies.

Comment: I will play with that and let you know what I end up with.  Makes sense.

Comment: I haven't had great success so far.  Been playing with it for a while but getting unwanted results.  Right now I am at the following `DECLARE @val int
SET @val = 43770
SELECT     oL.SERIAL_NUMBER
FROM         ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_OPTICS AS oL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS AS rL 
       ON rL.SERIAL_NUMBER != oL.SERIAL_NUMBER
       WHERE ol.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val;`

Comment: Why does the SQL query produce duplicate results with this method?  I am seeing 3 of every entry.

Comment: Thats why you need to post table structures etc. Knowing what the tables look like and what the tables _primary key_ is will help us to assist